# проблема с сетью на VPS FreeBSD 11

Tags: маршрутизация, vpn, vps, freebsd

На vps развернута FreeBSD 11 с внешним адресов A.A.A.A и поднят gre-туннель между mikrotik с внешним адресом B.B.B.B и этим сервером:

```
root@XXXXXX ~ # ifconfig gre0
gre0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1392
options=80000<LINKSTATE>
tunnel inet A.A.A.A --> B.B.B.B
inet 10.100.0.1 --> 10.100.0.2  netmask 0xffffffff 
nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
groups: gre 

root@XXXXXXX ~ # netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            X.X.X.X            UGS         xn0
10.100.0.1         link#4             UHS         lo0
10.100.0.2         link#4             UH         gre0
...
```

Когда я тестирую скорость в канале то скорость нормальная (вывод с консоли vps сервера):

```
root@XXXXXX ~ # iperf -s 10.100.0.1
iperf: ignoring extra argument 10.100.0.1

Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 64.0 KByte (default)

[  4] local 10.100.0.1 port 5001 connected with 10.100.0.2 port 21440
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  92.6 MBytes  77.5 Mbits/sec
```

Но если я запускаю iperf на внешнем интерфейсе vps и пытаюсь тестировать скорость через туннель до внешнего интерфейса, то она сильно падает (вывод с консоли vps сервера):

```
root@DS869040 ~ # iperf -s A.A.A.A
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- A.A.A.A
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 64.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local A.A.A.A port 5001 connected with 10.100.0.2 port 21751
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-107.2 sec   128 KBytes  9.78 Kbits/sec
```

Файервол не использую. 
Пробовал также поднять туннель с vps CentOS - эффект такой же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в фаерволе на Mikrotik в стандартном правиле fasttrack connection

Comment: Оформите, как пофиксили, может кому-то пригодится в будущем.